# NDK_APP_OUT doesn't work as advertised

Tags: android-ndk

There are places both here on StackOverflow and on other forums where people say the output directory for the "final.so" file in an NDK build can be specified thusly:

```
MY_APP_PATH_FOR_OUTPUT := $(call my-dir)
NDK_APP_OUT := $(MY_APP_PATH_FOR_OUTPUT)/../../buildresults/android
```

But when I do this there is no change in output location of the final product (MyLibrary.so).  It does put intermediate files ("local/armeabi/*") in that directory, but I need the final output to go there.

What's the way one is supposed to accomplish this?

Note: What I'm talking about is the very final build step that ndk-build labels "[armeabi] Install".  I'm building a .so file and want it to go into the directory I specify during that step.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `NDK_APP_LIBS_OUT` instead (it's undocumented but it works...). You have to directly pass it to ndk-build though:

```
ndk-build(.cmd) NDK_APP_LIBS_OUT=src/main/jniLibs
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it'll work.  But can I define a variable inside the top level Application.mk file (such as "MY_LIB_OUT := C:\TMP") and use that variable from the ndk-build command line?

Comment: yes, you can put `MY_LIB_OUT := C:/TMP` inside *Application.mk* and call `ndk-build.cmd NDK_APP_LIBS_OUT=$(MY_LIB_OUT)`